# Group by and calculate mean / average of properties in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, group-by

I struggled finding the solution I was looking for in other stackoverflow posts, even though I strongly feel as if it must exist. If it does, please do forward me in the right direction.

I am trying to do a pretty standard group by in javascript using sports data. I have the following array of objects:

```
 const myData = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27}
 ]
```

Each row in my data corresponds to the results of a specific basketball game. Simply put, I would like to group by the data, and apply a mean/average function to the grouped data. The results I would expect are:

```
const groupedData = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 118.3, ast: 27.0, reb: 25.3},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 101, ast: 15.5, reb: 37.5},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 134.7, ast: 21.3, reb: 29.7} 
]
```

I would prefer to use vanilla javascript with reduce() here... given what I know about reduce, it seems like the best way. I am currently working on this and will post if i can get it to work before someone else posts the answer.

EDIT: My actual data has ~30 keys. I am hoping to find a solution that simply asks me to either (a) specify only the team column to be grouped by, and assume it groups the rest, or (b) pass an array of stat columns (pts, asts, etc.) rather than creating a line for each stat.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do it in steps because you need to have all data in order to be able to average the points and the rest of the data

Comment: what do you mean when you say all data needs to be "in order"

Comment: in order as "in order to boil water you need to warm it up first". So first you need to group all data and then you need to go through it to calculate the average.

Comment: from the first couple of answers posted, i understand what you mean now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a JavaScript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: does the object have always the same keys?

Comment: (a) do you mean if you specify "GSW", only the team "GSW" need to be grouped and averaged?
(b) do you mean the columns to be averaged is sent as an array ? or the stats columns in the data are clubbed into an array ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `reduce` and `map` in conjunction.

```js
const myData = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27}
 ]
 
 // Calculate the sums and group data (while tracking count)
 const reduced = myData.reduce(function(m, d){
    if(!m[d.team]){
      m[d.team] = {...d, count: 1};
      return m;
    }
    m[d.team].pts += d.pts;
    m[d.team].ast += d.ast;
    m[d.team].reb += d.reb;
    m[d.team].count += 1;
    return m;
 },{});
 
 // Create new array from grouped data and compute the average
 const result = Object.keys(reduced).map(function(k){
     const item  = reduced[k];
     return {
         team: item.team,
         ast: item.ast/item.count,
         pts: item.pts/item.count,
         reb: item.reb/item.count
     }
 })
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,4));
```

EDIT: Just saw your update to the question. You can do away with each line for each key if you can either whitelist (provide an array of keys to compute) or blacklist (provide an array of keys to ignore) keys to do that programmatically.

```js
const myData = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27}
 ]
 
/**
 * Function which accepts a data array and a list of whitelisted
 * keys to find the average of each key after grouping
 */
function getGroupedData(data, whitelist) {
  // Calculate the sums and group data (while tracking count)
  const reduced = data.reduce(function(m, d) {
    if (!m[d.team]) {
      m[d.team] = { ...d,
        count: 1
      };
      return m;
    }
    whitelist.forEach(function(key) {
      m[d.team][key] += d[key];
    });
    m[d.team].count += 1;
    return m;
  }, {});

  // Create new array from grouped data and compute the average
  return Object.keys(reduced).map(function(k) {
    const item = reduced[k];
    const itemAverage = whitelist.reduce(function(m, key) {
      m[key] = item[key] / item.count;
      return m;
    }, {})
    return {
      ...item, // Preserve any non white-listed keys
      ...itemAverage // Add computed averege for whitelisted keys
    }
  })
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(getGroupedData(myData, ['pts', 'ast', 'reb']), null, 4));
```

Comment: if its not hard to update, feel free to assume that both are available

Comment: Updated my answer.. Not as big a difference as I had initially imagined (the average operation makes it necessary to do it verbosely)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myData = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27}
 ]

const groubElement = myData.reduce((obj, val) => {
    if (obj[val.team]) {
        obj[val.team].pts = obj[val.team].pts + val.pts;
        obj[val.team].ast = obj[val.team].pts + val.ast;
        obj[val.team].reb = obj[val.team].pts + val.reb;
        obj[val.team].counter = obj[val.team].counter + 1;
    } else {
        obj[val.team] = val;
        obj[val.team].counter = 1;
    }
    return obj;

}, {});



const groupElementWithMean = Object.values(groubElement).map(({
    counter,
    ...element
}) => {
    element.pts = (element.pts / counter).toFixed(1);
    element.ast = (element.ast / counter).toFixed(1);
    element.reb = (element.reb / counter).toFixed(1);
    return element;
});

console.log(groupElementWithMean);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `reduce` with `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map` as follows:-

```js
const myData = [
    { team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11 },
    { team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18 },
    { team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47 },
    { team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43 },
    { team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32 },
    { team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25 },
    { team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37 },
    { team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27 }
]

let grpData = myData.reduce((acc, cv) => {
    if (!acc[cv.team]) {
        acc[cv.team] = {};
        acc[cv.team].team = cv.team;
        acc[cv.team].count = acc[cv.team].pts = acc[cv.team].ast = acc[cv.team].reb = 0
    }
    acc[cv.team].count++;
    acc[cv.team].pts += cv.pts;
    acc[cv.team].ast += cv.ast;
    acc[cv.team].reb += cv.reb;
    return acc;
}, {});
grpData = Object.keys(grpData).map(key => {
    let { team, reb, ast, pts, count } = grpData[key];
    return {
        team, reb: reb / count, ast: ast / count, pts: pts / count
    };
})
console.log(grpData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using array of `statsFields` and loop over those to create totals and later to get averages

```js
const myData = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27}
 ]
 
 const statsFields = ['pts','ast','reb'];
 
 const teamsObject = myData.reduce((a,{team,...stats})=>{
   a[team] = a[team] || {team, games:0};
   a[team].games++
   statsFields.forEach(k=> a[team][k] = (a[team][k] || 0) + stats[k]);
   return a;
 },{});
 
 const res = Object.values(teamsObject).map(({games,...team})=>{
    // average for each field total/games
    statsFields.forEach(k=> team[k] = team[k]/games);    
    return team;
 })
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply done as follows.

Note: Used JSON.parse and stringify to deep shallow copy the data. Or else the original array gets modified. Its not needed if the original array can be modified.

```js
const data = [
    {team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18},
    {team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43},
    {team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37},
    {team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27}
 ];

function groupData(mydata,keys)
{
    var accresult = mydata.reduce(function(acc, value){
      var arr = acc.filter(function(obj){return obj.team==value.team});
      arr.length ? (item=arr[0] , keys.forEach(function(key){ item[key]+=value[key]; })) : acc.push(value);
      return acc;
  },[]);

  var result = accresult.map(function(val){
      var l = mydata.filter(function(obj){return obj.team==val.team}).length;
      keys.forEach(function(key){ val[key]=(val[key]/l).toFixed(2); })
      return val;
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(groupData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.slice(0))),['pts','ast']));
console.log(groupData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.slice(0))),['pts','ast','reb']));
console.log(groupData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.slice(0))),['pts']));
```

Comment: @Canovice Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a dynamic approach by using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and generate all items after collecting the unknown keys.

```js
function groupBy(array, key) {
    return Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, o) => {
            var temp = m.get(o[key]);
            if (!temp) {
                m.set(o[key], temp = {});
            }
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
                if (k === key) {
                    return;
                }
                temp[k] = temp[k]  || { sum: 0, count: 0 };
                temp[k].sum += v;
                temp[k].count++;
            });
            return m;
        }, new Map),
        ([k, v]) => Object.assign({ [key]: k }, ...Object.entries(v).map(([l, { sum, count }]) => ({ [l]: +(sum / count).toFixed(1) })))
    );
}

const myData = [{ team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11 }, { team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18 }, { team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47 }, { team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43 }, { team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32 }, { team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25 }, { team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37 }, { team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27 }];

console.log(groupBy(myData, 'team'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With rest properties (`babel: true`).

```js
function groupBy(array, key) {
    return Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { [key]: k, ...rest}) => {
            var temp = m.get(k);
            if (!temp) {
                m.set(k, temp = {});
            }
            Object.entries(rest).forEach(([l, v]) => {
                temp[l] = temp[l]  || { sum: 0, count: 0 };
                temp[l].sum += v;
                temp[l].count++;
            });
            return m;
        }, new Map),
        ([k, v]) => Object.assign({ [key]: k }, ...Object.entries(v).map(([l, { sum, count }]) => ({ [l]: +(sum / count).toFixed(1) })))
    );
}

const myData = [{ team: "GSW", pts: 120, ast: 18, reb: 11 }, { team: "GSW", pts: 125, ast: 28, reb: 18 }, { team: "GSW", pts: 110, ast: 35, reb: 47 }, { team: "HOU", pts: 100, ast: 17, reb: 43 }, { team: "HOU", pts: 102, ast: 14, reb: 32 }, { team: "SAS", pts: 127, ast: 21, reb: 25 }, { team: "SAS", pts: 135, ast: 25, reb: 37 }, { team: "SAS", pts: 142, ast: 18, reb: 27 }];

console.log(groupBy(myData, 'team'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is returning sums not averages

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myData = [
  { team: "GSW", pts: 120 },
  { team: "HOU", pts: 100 },
  { team: "GSW", pts: 110 },
  { team: "SAS", pts: 135 },
  { team: "HOU", pts: 102 },
  { team: "SAS", pts: 127 },
  { team: "SAS", pts: 142 },
  { team: "GSW", pts: 125 }
];

var result = myData.reduce(function (a, b) {
  var exist = -1;
  //some breaks the loop once it gets the true
  a.some((x, y) => {
    if (x.team == b.team) {
      //assigning index of existing object in array
      exist = y;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (exist == -1) {
    a.push({ team: b.team, pts: b.pts, count: 1 });
  } else {
    a[exist].count += 1;
    a[exist].pts += b.pts;
  }
  return a;
}, []).map(t => {return {team: t.team, avg: t.pts/t.count, count:t.count}});


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes